# Javascript indexOf String method returning multiple results

Tags: javascript, indexof

I'm iterating through a list of items in a table and have a search field. The item I'm searching has many very similar values (ticket numbers): for the most part `indexOf` works, but in some cases it returns multiple results.

If you're searching on a specific ticket number, it should only return that `<tr>` with the searched ticket value. In the following, `query` is the search value. If it is equal to -1, then skip over that. A check is then performed that `continue`s over to the filtered results and that will be rendered.

```
for (var i in data){
    var ticket = data[i].ticket.indexOf(query) === -1;

    if (ticket)
        continue;
    else {
        filtered_data.push(data[i]);
    }
}
```

An example: I search `ABC002465179`, it'll return the following:

`ABC002465179` `ABC002480483`, `ABC002480487`,`ABC002480494`, and `ABC002480265`

I've also toyed with the `match` method but am seeing the same results.

Any insight to what I am overlooking here?

Created a jsfiddle per a commenter: https://jsfiddle.net/7zrknwga/3/

Trying to reproduce there and I'm setting 1 result, as I should be.

**UPDATE:** was able to figure it out. As @KaeyangTheG suggested there was something else going on with filtered_data. There was another column in the filter (parent_ticket) that had the ability to be `null`: there was a check against that but when I moved the logic to check the indexOf piece plus the `null` aspect together (using `&&`), it was able to filter the correct results.

So the issue was never the indexOf check against `ticket`, but rather against `parent_ticket` because of the potential null values. `ticket` is never `null`

Comment: Can you give a runnable example in a Stack Snippet so we can reproduce the problem as well and debug it?

Comment: The problem is, `ticket` might be `0`. Actually, there seems to be no point in this loop as it `continue`s when it's truthy, so nothing gets pushed in except when `ticket` is `0`.

Comment: Sure, created a jsfiddle if that's ok.

Comment: I just run your code snippet and it works as it should and it's returning just 1 which is ABC002465179

Comment: well absent the entire context its impossible to say (yes I did see the fiddle).  Maybe `filtered_data` has been updated somewhere else in the code?  I would suggest you use a debugger and breakpoint specifically on those lines where filtered_data is getting pushed to in order to see what is up.  Hope this link helps: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know that a ticket that you are querying for exists in the data array then you can simply iterate the array and compare the ticket field with the `query` string.

```
// isFound is for tracking the ticket if it exist or not and indexOfTicket is for tracking its index.
let isFound = false;
let indexOfTicket = -1;

data.map((item, index)=>{
    if(item.ticket == query){
        isFound = true;
        indexOfTicket = index;
    }
})
if(isFound){
    console.log("Ticket "+data[indexOfTicket]+" is at "+(indexOfTicket)+' position');
}else {
    console.log("Not Found");
}
```

Comment: If you're not using the results of the callback functions, you should use `forEach()` rather than `map()`. And if you're searching for the first match, you should use `.find()`.

Comment: Yes, you are right but in `forEach()` you have no parameter for getting the index of the item. And as you can see the data is an Array of Objects so `find()` is not useful. You can use `findObject()` if you want but that will also just return the boolean value whether the object exists or not. In the above snippet, the index is the basic priority because of which I am using `map()`.

Comment: `forEach()` does have an index parameter. `findIndex()` is like `find()` but returns the index. There's no `findObject()` in JS.